# How to start an .exe file using input/output file and set a time limit in batch?

Tags: batch-file

In windows command prompt, when I want to run a program using input/output file, I always use batch command like the following: test.exe < input.in > output.out. 
(test.exe is the name of program, input.it is the name of input file and output.out is the name of output file)

But if I use this command, I cannot set a time limit for that program (i.e. I cannot force the program to quit after an amount of time).
So what command I should use in order to do that? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Could you install additional tools on your windows machine such as cygwin? The `timeout` command would elegantly solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start "" /b cmd /c "test.exe <input.in >output.out"
timeout /t 10
tasklist | find "test.exe" >nul && taskkill /f /im test.exe
```

Start the program inside a cmd instance not attached to the current console, wait for 10 seconds and if program still in task list, kill it

EDIT - Updated to handle the case pointed in comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    start "" /b cmd /c "test.exe <input.in >output.out"

    call :timeoutProcess "test.exe" 10
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Program has been killed
    ) else (
        echo Program has ended in time
    )

    exit /b


:timeoutProcess process timeout
    for /l %%t in (1 1 %~2) do (
        timeout.exe /t 1 >nul
        tasklist | find "%~1" >nul || exit /b 0
    )
    taskkill /f /im "%~1" >nul 
    exit /b 1
```

Comment: Another problem: When using your command, the timeout will always lasts for 10 seconds, but the program can end earlier. So can I terminate the timeout process immediately when the program end?

Comment: @skyvn: more logic needs more code. Included sample of usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command:

```
start test.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5
taskkill /im test.exe /f
```

Here it's killed after 5 seconds. You can specify any duration in seconds.